# Ошибка при Post запросе

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, jax-rs

Пытаюсь послать пост запрос и натыкаюсь на ошибку: `HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`

- Почему посылается GET ?
- Если просмотреть заголовки в chrome, 2 ответа : Post found , 405 Not Allowed.
- Не понятно почему сначало находит Post но после перенаправления на SSL посылает GET ?

  **Буду рад любой помощи!**

  ```
   <!-- Registration -->
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>coupon.register.Register</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/register/posting</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

  <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>RegisterPosting</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/register/posting</url-pattern>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>

  <user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
  ```

  ```
  @Path("/register")
  public class Register extends HttpServlet{


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1068653210561068853L;
  Connection con = null;

  @POST
  @Path("/posting")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void Registering(User user){

  System.out.println("Before Connection");

  ConnectionPool con_pool = ConnectionPool.con_instance;

  String register = "INSERT INTO users(nickname,first_name,last_name,password,type,email)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  PreparedStatement pre;

  try {

      pre = con.prepareStatement(register);
      pre.setString(1,user.getNickName());
      pre.setString(2,user.getFirstName());
      pre.setString(3,user.getLastName());
      pre.setString(4,user.getPassword());
      pre.setString(5,user.getType());
      pre.setObject(6,user.getEmail());
      pre.execute();

      System.out.println("In the register method");


  }catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){

      throw new DuplicateUser("Such user already exists in database");

  }catch (SQLException e1) {

      throw new DataBaseError("You have some problems that need to be fixed with your database..");
  }
  finally{

  try {
      con_pool.returnConnection(con);
  } catch (CouponSystemException e1) {
      throw new DataBaseError("You have some problems that need to be fixed with your database..");
  }

  try {
      con.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {

      throw new DataBaseError("You have some problems that need to be fixed with your database..");
  }
  ```

  }
  }
  }

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще по [спецификации](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) браузер должен послать **идентичный** запрос по указанному адресу, но с оговоркой:

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request using
> the POST method, the user agent must not automatically redirect the
> request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
> change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> ```
>    Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
>    receiving a 302 status code, some existing user agents will
>    erroneously change it into a GET request.
> ```

Если посмотреть в [исходники](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/url_request/url_request_job.cc#47) хрома:

```
std::string ComputeMethodForRedirect(const std::string& method,
                                     int http_status_code) {
  // For 303 redirects, all request methods except HEAD are converted to GET,
  // as per the latest httpbis draft.  The draft also allows POST requests to
  // be converted to GETs when following 301/302 redirects, for historical
  // reasons. Most major browsers do this and so shall we.  Both RFC 2616 and
  // the httpbis draft say to prompt the user to confirm the generation of new
  // requests, other than GET and HEAD requests, but IE omits these prompts and
  // so shall we.
  // See:
  // https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-17#section-7.3
  if ((http_status_code == 303 && method != "HEAD") ||
      ((http_status_code == 301 || http_status_code == 302) &&
       method == "POST")) {
    return "GET";
  }
  return method;
}
```

Т.е. хром изменяет метод на GET.

Comment: Спасибо за направление, а то всё перебрал уже отчаялся! 
Есть возможность както исправить данный запрос используя https и перенаправление?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov а что мешает сразу на https запрос посылать?

Comment: Нечего, просто на случай если посылается не с SSL connection то перенаправить на SSL.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov возможно на стороне клиента можно как-то поймать эту ситуацию, но я не силен в этом. Лучше сразу писать так, чтобы таких ситуаций не возникало.